# Calcular un día a partir de una fecha inicial y un intervalo de días

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

Me surgió una duda intentando realizar una calculadora menstrual en Python, y es que deseo conocer cuál es el siguiente día donde una mujer tiene su periodo.

Suponiendo que introduzco una variable estilo...

```
ultimo_dia = (2020,4,17)
cantidad_dias = (3)
dias_ciclo = (28)

calculadora(siguiente_dia)

OUTPUT:

2020,5,15
```

¿Alguna sugerencia? ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar `datetime` de la biblioteca estándar, en concreto `datime.date` para representar la fecha y luego sumar los días con  `datetime.timedelta`.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta


ultimo_dia = (2020, 4, 17)
dias_ciclo = 28

siguiente_dia = date(*ultimo_dia) + timedelta(days=dias_ciclo)
```

> ```
> >>> siguiente_dia
> datetime.date(2020, 5, 15)
> ```

Si quieres una tupla puedes hacer:

```
siguiente_dia = date(*ultimo_dia) + timedelta(days=dias_ciclo)
siguiente_dia = (siguiente_dia.year, siguiente_dia.month, siguiente_dia.day)
```

> ```
> >>> siguiente_dia
> (2020, 5, 15)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

La librería [`arrow`](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) es perfecta para estos casos:

```
cantidad_dias = 30
primer_dia = arrow.Arrow(2020,4,17)
```

Y obtenemos el siguiente día utilizando `shift(days=<numero de dias>)`...

```
primer_dia.shift(days=cantidad_dias)
```

En este caso concreto nos devuelve:

```
primer_dia.shift(days=cantidad_dias)
>>> <Arrow [2020-05-17T00:00:00+00:00]
```

Si quieres un formato concreto, usa [`format()`](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#format):

```
>>> primer_dia.shift(days=cantidad_dias).format('YYYY,MM,DD')
'2020,05,17'
>>> primer_dia.shift(days=cantidad_dias).format('YYYY,M,D')
'2020,5,17'
```